# python CustomTkinter when I open comboBox it moves out of window

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, customtkinter

When I open a combobox which has lot of value it moves out of window

```
screen = ct.CTk()
screen.geometry('400x200+600+300')
combo = ct.CTkComboBox(master=screen,values=[str(u) for u in range(8,33)] ,state="readonly",fg_color="red",border_color="blue",dropdown_fg_color="yellow",text_color="black",dropdown_text_color="black",)
combo.place(x=10,y=45)
```

I want to add a scrollbar and I want to see limited value like normal tkinter.